# Substitute for "For" Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am aware that a for-loop isn't the best thing to use in R. Please suggest an alternative to the snippet below:

`mat` is a 2-D matrix
`pos.scores` and `neg.scores` are 1-D matrices

I am trying to populate the `pos.scores` and `neg.scores` matrices using some computation (if-else statements).

```
for (i in 1:(ncol(mat)-1)) 
{
pos.scores[1,i]<-ifelse(sum(mat[,i]>0 & mat[,ncol(mat)]=="Positive")==0,0.000001,sum(mat[,i]>0 & mat[,ncol(mat)]=="Positive"))/nrow(mat)    
neg.scores[1,i]<-ifelse(sum(mat[,i]>0 & mat[,ncol(mat)]=="Negative")==0,0.000001,sum(mat[,i]>0 & mat[,ncol(mat)]=="Negative"))/nrow(mat)        
}
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that.

Comment: [More info on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: Try `colSums(mat[,-ncol(mat)]>0 & mat[, ncol(mat)]=='Positive')` instead

Comment: Thanks - this works!